# REST API and login outside meteor application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, meteor

I'm creating application using meteor and using meteor account packages, now I would like to create a chrome extension which will allow users to login using meteor user credentials (username, password) and use it's REST API.

I have two questions, what is the common experience of creating REST API using meteor and organizing users login outside meteor application.

I've noticed when user is logging into meteor account, browser saves username and token in local storage and I think, maybe there is a way to have similar design using chrome extension and meteor REST API, please let me know if anybody have similar experience.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I guess the REST API should be fit to your needs. As usual GET / POST requests to your meteor server.

I would try to rebuild the request that the accounts-base module makes to the backend server for the user login.